# The Entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a Linq to Entity Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Good day to all.

Im Having Entity or complex type cannot be encountered
This is the first time i encountered this type of error 
Someone Help me

```
    public IEnumerable<APPLICANT> GetApplicant()
    { 
        IEnumerable<APPLICANT> applicantdata = Cache.Get("applicants") as IEnumerable<APPLICANT>;

        IEnumerable<Profile> profiledata = Cache.Get("profiles") as IEnumerable<Profile>;




        if (applicantdata == null)
        {

            var applicantList = (from a in context.Profiles
                                 join app in context.APPLICANTs 
                                 on a.PROFILE_ID equals app.Profile_id
                                where app.APPLICANT_LogicalDelete == false
                                select new APPLICANT()
                                 {
               APPLICANT_LastName = a.Applicant_LASTNAME,
               APPLICANT_FirstName = a.Applicant_FIRSTNAME,
               APPLICANT_MiddleName = a.Applicant_MIDDLENAME,
               APPLICANT_Address = a.Applicant_ADDRESS,
               APPLICANT_City = a.Applicant_CITY,
               APPLICANT_Phone = a.Applicant_PHONE,
                APPLICANT_Email= a.Applicant_EMAIL
           });

            applicantdata = applicantList.Where(v => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(v.APPLICANT_LastName)).OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();

            if (applicantdata.Any())    
            {
                Cache.Set("applicants", applicantdata, 30);
            }
        }
        return applicantdata.ToList().Take(1000);

    }
```

And This is the line where i encounter the error
Thanks!

```
applicantdata = applicantList.Where(v => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(v.APPLICANT_LastName)).OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();
```

AND THE ERROR IN THE LINE ABOVE IS

System.NotSupportedException: The entity or complex type 'Model.APPLICANT' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I edited the question. 
the error is 

System.NotSupportedException: The entity or complex type 'Model.APPLICANT' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: You can't use String.IsNullorEmpty (or any other 'local' functions) with LINQ to Entities. It doesn't know how to convert that to a database function. It's a total pain.

Comment: tried to change it to 

Where(v => v.APPLICANT_LastName != null && v.APPLICANT_LastName != " ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> select new APPLICANT()
> ```

Entity Framework does not support this. It gets diagnosed when the query is used, not when the query is constructed, which is why the line where you get the exception is confusing.

You can construct any type that *isn't* also a database entity, including anonymous types, so you can do

```
select new
{
    a.Applicant_LASTNAME,
    a.Applicant_FIRSTNAME,
    a.Applicant_MIDDLENAME,
    a.Applicant_ADDRESS,
    a.Applicant_CITY,
    a.Applicant_PHONE,
    a.Applicant_EMAIL
}
```

and you can, if required, put those values back into `APPLICANT` objects after your query has finished executing.

Or, if appropriate, you can the `APPLICANT` directly:

```
select app
```

I'm not sure why you have `Applicant_LASTNAME` etc. in both `Profile` and `APPLICANT`, and I do not know if the values are the same. If they are not, this last suggestion won't be of use to you.

Comment: After hours and hours of searching, finally found my problem! Thank you so much for your explanation!!!!

Comment: This is obviously an older post, but does anyone know if the selected solution is any better/worse than using a DTO?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you need to convert to Queryable objects.

```
applicantdata = applicantList.AsQueryable().Where(v => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(v.APPLICANT_LastName)).OrderBy(v => v.APPLICANT_ID).ToList();
```